# Python: Calculating the area enclosed by a contour using multi-threading friendly code

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I would like to extend [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772580/python-calculating-the-area-of-a-contour?noredirect=1#comment72664955_42772580) to find the area of a contour in a multi-threading friendly way.

I've tried the following code:

```
    c = cntr.Cntr(Z, X_, radial)
    # Trace a contour at calc_levels
    for loop in range(len(calc_levels)):
        res = c.trace(calc_levels[loop])
        # result is a list of arrays of vertices and path codes
        # (see docs for matplotlib.path.Path)
        nseg = len(res) // 2
        segments = res[:nseg]
        area = PolyArea(segments[0][:,0], segments[0][:,1])

def PolyArea(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))
```

In which I've tried adapting the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304722/python-find-contour-lines-from-matplotlib-pyplot-contour) and where the code for PolyArea comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates) But 1) the calculation of the area is not quite correct and 2) it slows down my multi-threaded code.

I say that the area is not correct because with the following code, which I spent a long time checking, I get completely different answers. However, this code is DEFINITELY NOT multi-threading compatible and causes the whole code to grind to a halt

```
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
    cs = ax1.contour(Z,X_,radial, levels = calc_levels,colors='k')
    for loop in range(len(calc_levels)):
        vs = None
        contour_ = None
        contour_ = cs.collections[loop]
        vs = contour_.get_paths()[0].vertices
        # Compute area enclosed by vertices
        features['Radial_Area_' + mystr + str(int(thisLevels[loop]*100))] = area(vs)
```

Is anyone able to help me either debug the first section of code, or write something different that will work better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I wasn't comparing like with like. Now looking at the same file I see that the calculated areas are the same! So the code

```
c = cntr.Cntr(Z, X_, radial)
# Trace a contour at calc_levels
for loop in range(len(calc_levels)):
    res = c.trace(calc_levels[loop])
    # result is a list of arrays of vertices and path codes
    # (see docs for matplotlib.path.Path)
    nseg = len(res) // 2
    segments = res[:nseg]
    area = PolyArea(segments[0][:,0], segments[0][:,1])

def PolyArea(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))
```

Does work how I thought it should and is much faster than the other code.

I will delete this post later giving those who are looking at time to see my answer

Comment: If you can extent this to a [mcve], you can as well keep it, as it may be useful for others. If you decide not to produce a minimal example, you can  delete it, because it will not help much.