# Calculate area of KDE contours in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, kde-plasma

So I've done a KDE in python via the following:

```
y = coords[:,1]   ## A set of y coordinates of the red points
x = coords[:,0]   ## A set of x coordinates of the red points
k = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x, y]))
k.set_bandwidth(bw_method=k.factor / 2.)

xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():x.size**0.8*1j,y.min():y.max():y.size**0.8*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 8))

for coord in coordsold:
  cv2.circle(sample,
           (coord[1],coord[0]),2,
            (220, 0, 0), 1)

ax.contourf(yi, xi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), alpha=0.5)
    
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.imshow(sample)
```

What I want to figure out is the area that the contours take up.  I thought that maybe I could turn the contours into polygon objects and then calculate the area that way, but I'm not sure. If anyone has a clever solution that would be greatly appreciated.

See attached:

[image: Contours around points]

Comment: please add a minimum running example.  What are values for `coords` for example?

Comment: This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678990/how-can-i-calculate-the-area-within-a-contour-in-python-using-the-matplotlib) will be helpful to you.