# How to calculate areas of multiple polygons within contours in python

Tags: python, polygon, area, surface

I have a dataframe with all the recorded positions (X, Y) over a surface. I would like to calculate the surface of the territory that the animal occupies during the entire study period.

Here is a part of my original dataframe with all locations:

```
> X                  Y
> 5508.695055    5000.133944  
> 5509.405078    5000.794318
> 5509.399589    5000.608576
> 5508.822574    5000.658109
> 5508.752179    5000.757261  
> 5514.831466    4989.379770
> 5514.388758    4989.025955
> 5515.196170    4989.357183
> 5515.755913    4989.102731
> 5515.098742    4988.847782
```

Following the `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678990/how-can-i-calculate-the-area-within-a-contour-in-python-using-the-matplotlib` 's advice, I used the Green's theorem to compute the area enclosed within the polygon contour. To drawn the polygon with contours I used the seaborn kernel density estimator function (`kdeplot`), which is the usual method to calculate the animals' home range. Here is my code:

```
> import numpy as np
> import matplotlib.pylab as plt
> import seaborn as sns
> 
> #Use Greens theorem to compute the area
> #enclosed by the given contour.
> def area(vs):
> a = 0
> x0,y0 = vs[0]
> for [x1,y1] in vs[1:]:
> dx = x1-x0
> dy = y1-y0
> a += 0.5*(y0*dx - x0*dy)
> x0 = x1
> y0 = y1
> return a
> 
> #Plot the polygon with contour according to kernel density estimator
> fig,ax=plt.subplots()
> kde = sns.kdeplot(data=DfHR, x='X', y='Y', shade=True, ax=ax, levels=[0.05,1], cmap="Reds", alpha=0.9)
> #Use the function 'area' to calculate the polygon surface in meters
> for i in range(len(levels)):
> contour = kde.collections[0]
> vs = contour.get_paths()[0].vertices
> #Compute area enclosed by vertices.
> a = area(vs)
> print("r = " + str(levels[i]) + ": a =" + str(a))
> 
> plt.show()
```

Which give the following image and the surface area in square meter:

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wvqa.png)

The script works pretty well when I have only one polygon, but with multiple polygons (as in the example) it do not calculate the exact area of the surface. To solve it I tried the following code which it is supposed to handle multiple islands (found here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678990/how-can-i-calculate-the-area-within-a-contour-in-python-using-the-matplotlib`):

```
> `fig,ax=plt.subplots()
> kde = sns.kdeplot(data=DfHR, x='X', y='Y', shade=True, ax=ax, levels=[0.05,1], cmap="Reds", alpha=0.9)
> 
> for i in range(len(levels)):
> contour = kde.collections[i]
> vs = contour.get_paths()
> area = 0
> for island in vs:
> ai = np.abs(area(island.vertices))
> area += ai
> print("r = " + str(levels[i]) + ": a =" + str(a))
> plt.show()`
```

That give this error:

```
> `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`
```

Do you have some ideas to fix this problem? Many thanks

Comment: Isn't it easier to use [@Jason's vectorized and simplified answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47950623/13285707)?

Comment: Can't you use Shapely? https://pypi.org/project/shapely/

Comment: Change the name of `area = 0` to for example `a` to avoid a conflict with the function call `area()`. Don't forget to change also to `a += ai`.